# updating dict values using a class method in python

Tags: python, class, dictionary, oop

I have a to use a class attribute that sets the default key:value pairs as shown:

```
class ElectronicMedicalRecord():
    def __init__(self, default_emr_config = {"language": 'english', "hospital_campus": 'PSOM', "emr_vendor": 'Epic'}):
        self.default_emr_config = default_emr_config
```

However, I have to now define a new method called "set_default_emr_config" to prompt a user to update the values of the key:value pairs to something new. I tried to do this:

```
class ElectronicMedicalRecord():
    def __init__(self, default_emr_config = {"language": 'english', "hospital_campus": 'PSOM', "emr_vendor": 'Epic'}):
        self.default_emr_config = default_emr_config
        
    def set_default_emr_config(self, default_emr_config):
        self.default_emr_config = default_emr_config
        
EMR = ElectronicMedicalRecord()
print(EMR.default_emr_config)

EMR.set_default_emr_config({"language": 'spanish', "hospital_campus": 'Drexel', "emr_vendor": 'Not Epic'})
print(EMR.default_emr_config)
```

But this is obviously not done using user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the dictionary and give the user the option to  keep the current value or update it.

Try this code:

```
class ElectronicMedicalRecord():
    def __init__(self, default_emr_config = {"language": 'english', "hospital_campus": 'PSOM', "emr_vendor": 'Epic'}):
        self.default_emr_config = default_emr_config
        
    def set_default_emr_config(self, default_emr_config):
        self.default_emr_config = default_emr_config
        
EMR = ElectronicMedicalRecord()
print(EMR.default_emr_config)

newdict = {}
for k in EMR.default_emr_config:
   v = input(f'Value for {k} [{EMR.default_emr_config[k]}]: ').strip()
   if v == "":
       newdict[k] = EMR.default_emr_config[k]  # keep current value
   else:
       newdict[k] = v  # new value

EMR.set_default_emr_config(newdict)
print(EMR.default_emr_config)
```